# How to split a single file in multple files by a string in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, split, export

Good day all,

I have a single txt file of batched text faxes broken by FCL codes as seen below:

```
{{begin}}
Fax information
{{end}}
{{begin}}
Fax information
{{end}}
{{begin}}
Fax information
{{end}}
```

There are over a hundred faxes in the single txt.  I need a powershell script to take txt between each `{{begin}}` and `{{end}}` and create a new txt file with just that txt for each fax.  So out of this one file the script creates one hundred individual txt files with a single `{{begin}}` fax text `{{end}}`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you edit your post and share some sample code with us so that we can assist you?  Your question in its current state may be in danger of being put on hold for showing minimal effort in attempting to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
#Variables#####
$file = $args[0]
$content = Get-Content $file
$c = ""
$i = 0
###############

foreach($f in $content)
{
    if($f -eq "{{end}}"){$i += 1; $c >> .\file$i.txt; $c = "";}
    if($f -ne "{{begin}}" -and $f -ne "{{end}}"){ $c += $f}
}
```

This will parse out the begin and end tags and then insert any of the content between each of those sets of tags into a seperate file. You can change the word file to anything that you would like those files to be called.

Also, as the above posters mentioned, it would be helpful to provide some sample code in the future to show what you have tried so that others can help you rather than have to start from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and effort.  This is more advanced than I know at this point.  I have never used variables in PS, so that is why what I had tried was basically useless.  I tried running your script but it errors out at: The term 'file' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
and try again.  + file <<<<  = $args[0] + CategoryInfo     : ObjectNotFound: (file:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException . Consider me a beginner. Thank you

Comment: Sorry that was a type on my part. I needed a $ prior to file in the script. This way all you have to do is call the script in the following manner:    Scriptname.ps1 PathTo/Fax/Files

Comment: Thank you again.  I am calling .\scriptSplit.psq D:\powershellscripts\fileToSplit1.txt, but it just returns to the prompt, no errors and not files created.  The txt I have should create 3 fax files.  I am using your original script above, so where does the $ you mentioned go?  I have messed around with it, but can't seem to make it fly.  Your help and expertise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the script.  Do you have any idea on my last reply of Sept 3rd?  The .psq is a typo, its ps1.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
$file = Get-Content single.txt
$pattern = "{{begin}}(.*?){{end}}"

$results = [regex]::Matches($file,$pattern)
$i = 0

foreach($result in $results)
{
    $i = $i + 1
    Out-File -InputObject $result.Groups[1].Value NewFile-$i.txt
}
```